# waiting for a user to finish typing AND check to see if its a set answer javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, addeventlistener

im making a textbased adventure and so i want to make the user make a choises so i want to make a function that will wait for the user to type something and then check if it is a valid response

```
exmpl:
do you want to visit the caves or the mountains?
a)caves
b)mountains
```

and then it would call a function that checks an input tag to see if 1) they finished typing and 2)its either 'a' or 'b' AND 3) if it isn't either a or b, it clears the input tag, and loops over

i have a function that waits for the user to finish typing

```
function list(){
    input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout=setTimeout(function(){
            ret = '';
            ret = input.value;
            input.value = '';
        },1000);
        input.removeEventListener('keyup');
    });
};
```

i tried putting in a while loop with another timer but it either slows it down or calls the list function 1000's of times

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the event triggers for each key, but they do not share state, your timer also makes things more complex and confusing. What you want is to keep your game state inside a structure, and have function acting on the structure given an input. Your input handler simply sends the user input into those handlers, which evaluates your game state and changes it based on the user input.

Example:

```js
let game =  {
   currentRoom: 2,
   rooms : [{
     name: "Forest",
     doors: [
      {
        name: "North",
        key: "a",
        leadsTo: "Mountain"
      },
      { 
        name: "West",
        key: "b",
        leadsTo: "Village"
      }
     ]
   },
   {
     name: "Mountain",
     doors: [{
       name: "South",
       key: "a",
       leadsTo: "Forest"
     }]
   },
   {
     name: "Village",
     doors: [
      {
        name: "East",
        key: "a",
        leadsTo: "Forest"
      }
     ]
   }
   ]
};

function printState(){
  let console = document.getElementById("console");
  console.innerHTML = `You are in ${game.rooms[game.currentRoom].name}<br>`;
  console.innerHTML += `Where do you want to go? <br>`;
  for(let door of game.rooms[game.currentRoom].doors){
    console.innerHTML += ` ${door.name} (${door.key})`;
  }
}

function evaluateUserInput(input){
  let currentRoom = game.rooms[game.currentRoom];
  for(let door of game.rooms[game.currentRoom].doors){
    if(input === door.key){
      let nextRoom = game.rooms.filter(r=>r.name === door.leadsTo)[0];
      let id = game.rooms.indexOf(nextRoom);
      game.currentRoom = id;
    }
  }
}
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=>{
  evaluateUserInput(e.key);
  printState();
});
printState();
```

```html
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: what if i wanted to include the option of double clicking a button as another option, for example:
going to forest was 'a'
going to mountain was 'aa'
that's why i had the timer thing.

Comment: in that case add a buffer and fill that buffer until you reach a command you want to react to, then reset the buffer to empty after executing a command. If you want it to be the same key, then you will need to add some kind of "end of statement" message. Like "a"+ the enter key, and evaluate the buffer once the EOS key is read.